# Unexpected result of the rule

Tags: prolog

I have tried to write a rule that checks if a list is a chain like:
[[5,2],[2,4]] - true
[[7,2],[4,0]] - false
[[1,2]] - false, single element lists are not chains too.

So, pattern is like `[[a,b], [b,c], [c,d], ...]` (inner lists always contain two elements and any of a, b, c, d... might be equal).

```
chain([]):-!.
chain([X]):-false.
chain([_|[]]):-!.
chain([[_, X2]|[[Y1, Y2]|Tail]]):-
    X2 == Y1,
    chain([[Y1, Y2]|Tail]).
```

With
`-? chain([[1,2]]).` I got true, which confuses me.

Also I've tried to replace second line with `chain(L):-length(L, Len),Len>1.`, but the result remains the same.

I appreciate any help and explanation.

Comment: Can you explain with your own words what is a "chain"? Minimum length of it, minimum length of the single links in the chain? Are they necessarily integers or can they be other Prolog terms? and so on. Too much to guess at the moment. For example, is this a chain: `[[1],[1]]`? How about this: `[[a,b],[b,a]]`?

Comment: how about this: `[[1,1,1],[1]]`? Or are the links always exactly 2 elements?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained this in more detail. In my case values are always integers. Inner lists are more like tuples than actually lists, their length always should be 2. So, pattern I want to check is [[a, b], [b, c], [c, d], ...], including the case when any of these values are equal.

Comment: So is it so that the "chain" has 2 or more links in it, where every link is a pair, and the first element of the pair is the same as the second element of the previous pair? No other constraints (because in all your examples you also have the elements monotonously increasing... is this a chain: `[[a, b], [b,a]]`?

Comment: (you should add any additional info to the question by editing it; do not put relevant info in comments because it is easy to overlook)

Comment: Question is updated too. Thanks for the comments. And yes, there are no other special constraints and ```[[a, b], [b,a]]``` is a chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly fail. Just don't write a rule for that case, the rule will then fail because it can't succeed.

Here is one way to do it:

```
chain([[_,X],[X,Y]|Rest]) :-
    chain_1(Rest, Y).

chain_1([], _).
chain_1([[X,Y]|Rest], X) :-
    chain_1(Rest, Y).
```

Does that work for all your corner cases?

---

There is very little to explain here. If something isn't obvious ask specific questions.

Because there is a certain obsession with the most general query around these parts, and I am a natural crowd pleaser, I will do as the Romans do:

```
?- chain(X).
X = [[_, _A], [_A, _]] ;
X = [[_, _A], [_A, _B], [_B, _]] ;
X = [[_, _A], [_A, _B], [_B, _C], [_C, _]] ;
X = [[_, _A], [_A, _B], [_B, _C], [_C, _D], [_D, _]] .
```

Cool!

Since chain_1/2 is a left fold on the list, you could write this as:

```
chain([[_,X],[X,Y]|Rest]) :-
    foldl(chain_rule, Rest, Y, _).

chain_rule([X,Y], X, Y).
```

Doesn't get more readable but you can show off to your friends.

Comment: It works perfectly!  Thanks a lot for answering such noob questions! I think there is no need to explain something, this example is very clear. Thanks!